# rzc discover exited with code -2147450743

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor

I am getting the error

> "rzc discover exited with code -2147450743"

...error when i try to compile my web app. When I click on the error it takes me to the RazorTagHelper line:

```
   <RazorTagHelper
             Debug="$(_RazorDebugTagHelperTask)"
             DebugTool="$(_RazorDebugTagHelperTool)"
             ToolAssembly="$(_RazorToolAssembly)"
             UseServer="$(UseRazorBuildServer)"
             ForceServer="$(_RazorForceBuildServer)"
             SuppressCurrentUserOnlyPipeOptions="$(_RazorSuppressCurrentUserOnlyPipeOptions)"
             PipeName="$(_RazorBuildServerPipeName)"
             Version="$(RazorLangVersion)"
             Configuration="@(ResolvedRazorConfiguration)"
             Extensions="@(ResolvedRazorExtension)"
             Assemblies="@(RazorReferencePath)"
             ProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
             TagHelperManifest="$(_RazorTagHelperOutputCache)">
             <Output
               TaskParameter="TagHelperManifest"
               ItemName="FileWrites"/>
           </RazorTagHelper>
```

Things that I've done to try fix the error

- Updated .Net Core to 2.1
- Repair VS2019
- Updated VS2019

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error and this is how I resolved it.

*I have multiple .NET SDKs installed, so trust me this wasn't the issue for me.*

- I looked at the Output window when the Rebuild Solution gave me that error.
- In the output window I noticed that there was an SDK missing error. I
  just installed the specific SDK and restarted Visual Studio.
- When performed Rebuild solution the next time, it built successfully

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by going to Visual Studio Installer > Modify > Individual Components, and select the component that I was missing eg. Netcore 2.2.
[image]

Comment: In my case, it is actually installing the .Net Core 2.1 Runtime (LTS) resolved this issue. I sure hope I know where it is referenced as I've checked all projects are on .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

It indicates missing runtime version. It may be that there are two versions of runtime version installed in the computer.

[image]

Comment: I tried uninstalling all of the duplicated runtime versions in my machine and i restarted it to make sure, but still no luck the error still persists. Would you mind looking into my install sdks and runtimes ? here's the link to my screenshots: [Sdks and Runtimes](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M7g5_86JmGKD7yAdGmJL4pbMGCq41Y_g?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ElmarGuevarra, it seems that there are many versions on your machine. I have only one sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by **Reinstalling .NET SDk**.